# Make a relative child element inside parent if parent height is short

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, vertical-alignment

Recently I had a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310563/keep-relatively-positioned-child-within-parent-block-max-top-equivalent-needed) with a brilliant answer. However, that answer and that question are not applicable to today's situation. Now the button has text under it. 
Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/Lo4362rk/

```
button {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 10%;
  top: 100px;
  max-top: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
.third-party-block {
  //display: none;
}
```

and

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;">
  <button>
   The main thing in the text is here =>
  </button>
  <p class="third-party-block">
     some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here 
  </p>
</div>
```

The .third-party-block is dynamic and sometimes it is not displayed. As result, the parent becomes shorter and the button becomes outside of the parent because of top: 100px;
The question is how to push the button inside of the parent let's say to the 10px from the top (not from 100px).

Pure CSS solution is needed.

[image]

Comment: I'm really unclear on what this is supposed to look like with and without the third-party div.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I have added an image for two cases: long text and short text. The blue arrow on the image says the button should be pushed closer to the top, the css solution is preferable. Is it more clear now? Thank you.

Comment: Why would you do that? Are you trying have the text flow around a bottom positioned button.

Comment: To simplify my question I used a text. In reality it's a third party block on the page. I've tried to position the button with css without any javascript for two different cases. @Temani Afif  proved it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use position:absolute where you can set `max-height`/`min-height` and you consider the `height` with percentage value:

```css
.parent {
  position:relative;
}

.button {
  position:absolute;
  right:10%;
  top:0;
  height:40%;
  min-height:30px;
  max-height:120px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
button {
  margin-top:auto;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div style="border:1px solid red;" class="parent">
  <div class="button"><button>
   The main thing in the text is here =>
  </button></div>
  <p class="third-party-block">
     some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here somesome text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some
  </p>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid red;" class="parent">
  <div class="button"><button>
   The main thing in the text is here =>
  </button></div>
  <p class="third-party-block">
     some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here 
  </p>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid red;" class="parent">
  <div class="button"><button>
   The main thing in the text is here =>
  </button></div>
  <p class="third-party-block">
     some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes 
  </p>
</div>

<div style="border:1px solid red;" class="parent">
  <div class="button"><button>
   The main thing in the text is here =>
  </button></div>
  <p class="third-party-block">
     some text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes eme text comes here some text comes here some text comes here some text comes 
  </p>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid red;" class="parent">
  <div class="button"><button>
   The main thing in the text is here =>
  </button></div>
  <p class="third-party-block">
     some text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is so tricky, smart and cool. One of the best solutions I've ever seen made with CSS.